# Webpack server bundling exclude CSS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am using react server side rendering, while bulding my server.js file i want to exclude all css imports. Is there a way to bundle it without including css-loaders in my server webpack file?

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> .a4-layout.a4-hidden {
```

Comment: Don't include css loaders and don't import your css on your main js file. It won't know where it is /if it exists and won't bundle it. If you're looking to create a different css file then you need [miniCssExtractPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) but that means you'll need to include css loaders.

Comment: @Jabberwocky hey thanks for responding. What i am stating is i'm importing css in my react components but while bundling server it is giving me an error. I am updating my question with error.

Comment: looks like a css loader is what you need. Why do you want to not use it?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes i have it in client webpack but why would i need it in server webpack?